# Como tipar corretamente uma interface para utilizar no mongoose com typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, back-end

Boa tarde, estou com um pequeno problema que me tira o sono a um tempo, resolvi parcialmente mas não sei se é a melhor forma de fazê-lo, por isso se alguém já passou por isso e puder me ajudar serei grato.

Imagine a seguinte situação: tenho dois models e suas devidas interfaces, e um dos models tem uma propriedade que é do tipo da interface do outro. A propriedade em questão é "perfil"

```js
// Interfaces
interface IUser {
  nome: string;
  sobrenome: string;
  perfil: Types.ObjectId & IPerfil;
}

interface IPerfil {
  nome: string;
  codigo: number;
}

// Schemas
const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
  nome: { type: String, required: true },
  sobrenome: { type: String, required: true },
  perfil: {
    type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    ref: "Perfil",
  },
});

const perfilSchema = new Schema<IPerfil>({
  nome: { type: String, required: true },
  codigo: { type: Number, required: true },
});
```

Ali na interface de usuário eu utilizei um operador de intersection para que quando eu recupere aquele schema via find().populate("perfil"), eu consiga ter acesso a todas as propriedades sem precisar utilizar type guards pra isso. Da mesma forma, um find normal continuaria me dando acesso a propriedade _id da mesma, sem precisar dar populate.

Não sei se isso é uma boa prática, mas optei por esse caminho pois não sei como fazer a asserção correta disso utilizando o union "|" ao invés do intersection "&". Alguém que utiliza o mongoose com typescript pode me dar uma luz, é problemático fazer isso?

---

Obrigado a quem se respondeu, pensando melhor em questão de arquitetura vi que não vale a pena fazer o que eu pensava. Uma vez que o único lugar onde é útil passar uma interface como subelemento de outro é no populate, resolvi seguir a documentação, e quando for preciso eu faço a tipagem correta

Comment: Por que não colocar o id dentro da interface IPerfil?

Comment: E remover o  Types.ObjectId  de perfil: Types.ObjectId & IPerfil;?

Answer (score -2):

```
user-model.ts
export const UserModel = {
  nome: {
    type: string,
    required: true
    };
  sobrenome: {
    type: string,
    required: true
    };
  perfil: {
    type: {
       nome: string,
       codigo: number
       }
    }
}
export interface User extends Document {
  _id: Types.ObjectId
}
Ja no arquivo de interface voce typa da forma convencional, e no arquivo de schema:

users-schema.ts
const usersSchema = new Schema(UserModel, {timestamps: true})
const UsersSchema = = model<IUser>('users', usersSchema)
//Onde IUser é a sua interface que voce typou o campo perfil: IPerfil
```